# Django ORM - LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Column = 123

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

**What i whant to achieve:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/dccc4/5

**DB Scheme:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
 idTable1 integer primary key
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
  idTable1 integer,
  user_id integer,
  num integer
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (idTable1) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Table1 (idTable1) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO Table2 (idTable1, user_id, num) VALUES (1, 11, 111);
INSERT INTO Table2 (idTable1, user_id, num) VALUES (1, 22, 222);
```

**Raw SQL query:**

```sql
SELECT    T1.idTable1,
          IFNULL(T2.num, 0) num
FROM      Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 
ON        T1.idTable1 = T2.idTable1 
AND       T2.user_id  = 11
WHERE     T1.idTable1 = 1
```

**Resulting QuerySet**:

```sql
| idTable1 | num |
|----------|-----|
|        1 | 111 |
```

Is it possible to code using Django ORM?

**UPDATE**

**Models are:**

```python
class Table1(models.Model):
    # ...

class Table2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)

    num = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

objects = Table1.objects.filter(
              Q(table2__isnull=True) | Q(table2__user=11),
              id=1
          ).annotate(
              num=Coalesce('table2__num', V(0))
          ).values('id', 'num')
```

It is `LEFT JOIN`, but I don't know if Django can construct `AND` part in queries like `... LEFT JOIN ... ON ... AND ... WHERE`. In this case, end result is the same (I hope).

Comment: That gives me INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN: 

SELECT "myApp_Table1"."idTable1", COALESCE("myApp_Table2"."number", 0) AS "number" FROM "myApp_Table1" INNER JOIN "myApp_Table2" ON ( myApp_Table1"."idTable1" = "myApp_Table2"."idTable1" ) WHERE ( "myApp_Table2"."user_id" = 11 AND "myApp_Table1"."idTable1" = 1 )

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!